# Transparent pixel in nginx error log...Is this hacking?

Tags: nginx

I'm assuming this is a hacker, but what gives here.

> 2016/05/06 20:10:01 [error] 11878#0: *4135 open() "/usr/local/www/nginx/MYDOMAIN/public_html/images/G/01/x-loc
>   ale/common/transparent-pixel.*CB386942464*.gif" failed (2: No such file or directory), client: 42.159.144.101, server:
>    MYDOMAIN, request: "GET [http://g-ecx.images-amazon.com/images/G/01/x-locale/common/transparent-pixel.*CB38694*](http://g-ecx.images-amazon.com/images/G/01/x-locale/common/transparent-pixel._CB38694)
>   2464.gif HTTP/1.0", host: "g-ecx.images-amazon.com"

Answer (score 5):

Someone sent a request asking your server to fetch that image from Amazon, and your server interpreted it as a local file which it then failed to find (which is a good thing).

They were probing for an open proxy, which would return any requested URL to them.  This would let them visit any web site and as far as the site could tell the traffic would all come from you (although proxies and the true originating address can often?sometimes? be detected).